# VBscript to run a file path located in my .xml

Tags: xml, batch-file, vbscript

i have generated .xml document which is basically a playlist with a file path to my media files. i'm trying to use a vbscript that reads the .xml document and executes a file path. i'm stuck with a .vbs to .bat, when executed "the system cannot find the file \movieserver.." it seems that the spaces in the file path are causing the problem. If there are no spaces the file will execute. How can i overcome this? This is what i have:

```
    Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, path
    Dim WshShell
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.load("C:\Apps\Code\VLCVersion4.0\trackList.xml")
    Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filepath")
    If objNodeList.length > 0 then
    For each x in objNodeList
    path=x.Text
    set WshShell=Wscript.Createobject("Wscript.shell")
    wshshell.run "vbs-to-bat.bat " & path
    Next
    Else
    msgbox chr(34) & "filepath" & chr(34) & " field not found."
    End If
```

and the batch file it runs

```
    @echo off

    %1

    exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Double) Quote the file spec -

```
wshshell.run "vbs-to-bat.bat " & path
```

==>

```
wshshell.run "vbs-to-bat.bat " & """" & path & """"
```

(BTW: You may want to look at your error message again)

Comment: that works great! but for some reason when i run this using the task scheduler it fails "path not found" when i run it manually it works great. any idea?

Comment: @user3674251 - try to give the full path to the .bat.